# Error compiling Matlab MEX files (Piotr's Matlab Toolbox)

Tags: matlab, gcc, ubuntu, mex

I am trying to install Piotr's Matlab Toolbox (http://vision.ucsd.edu/~pdollar/toolbox/doc/) but the compile script for the mex files complains:

```
>> toolboxCompile
Compiling.......................................

Warning: You are using gcc version "4.6.3-1ubuntu5)".  The version
     currently supported with MEX is "4.2.3".
     For a list of currently supported compilers see: 
     http://www.mathworks.com/support/compilers/current_release/

/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lstdc++
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

mex: link of ' "/home/josh/Desktop/Project/code/toolbox/images/private/assignToBins1.mexglx"' failed.

??? Error using ==> mex at 222
Unable to complete successfully.

Error in ==> toolboxCompile at 36
for i=1:length(fs), mex([fs{i} '.c'],opts{:},[fs{i} '.' mexext]);
end
```

How do I go about resolving this issue?

Comment: did you install g++? seems you don't have a C++ library.

Answer (score 2):

1. Before you compile mexfiles in matlab you need to configure your mex compiler.

   In matlab, type:

   ```
   >> mex -setup
   ```

   Matlab automatically detects what compilers you have installed on your machine and allows you to pick one of them.
   On Linux machines you should use gcc compiler.
2. Another thing you must take care of is to make sure your environment variable `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` points to where your machine's libraries are installed.
   In matlab you may type:

   ```
   >> getenv('LD_LIBRARY_PATH')
   ```

   and make sure it is correct.
3. Try editing `toolboxCompile.m` and add `-v` to the mex compilation command to get more verbose information on the compilation.

Comment: Thanks Shai; some of this info was quite useful. The compilation proceeds however it stalls further with "SSE2 instruction set not enabled".

Comment: @Josh - I'm not familiar with this error. Last time I installed this toolbox it went smoothly both on Linux and windows. Try see if there's some doc on installation in the toolbox itself.

Answer (score 2):

**If you are a Linux (Ubuntu but other distro should be work) user:**

1. In order to use some system libraries instead Matlab default libraries add this environment variable to your bashrc (~/.bashrc):

   LD_PRELOAD=/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6:/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6:/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1;
2. Install g++-multilib:

   apt-get install g++-multilib
3. If you are running on a 32 bit machine edit toolboxCompile.m file and replace the line of code:

   "opts = {'-output'}" with
   "opts = {'CXXFLAGS=-msse2 -msse' '-output'}"